# silverstripe edit attribute of has_one relationship directly via textfield

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I am trying to edit an attribute of a related dataobject directly via a textfield. for example I have a counter object related to every page. I would be very handy to edit the value of the counter object directly via a textfield instead of going to the related object and edit it there. is that possible?

I can at least display the current value in the textfield like that: `$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('ILikeCount.Count', 'ILikeCount', $this->ILikeCount()->Count), 'Content');`

but saving new values does not work.
many thanx,
florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could catch the textField value in the `onBeforeWrite()` hook

```
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new TextField('ILikeCountCount', 'ILikeCount', $this->ILikeCount()->Count), 'Content');
```

The textField name can be anything, here I've just removed the dotted notation to make things easier. Then catch the value in `onBeforeWrite()` and update the relation.

```
public function onBeforeWrite()
{
    if( $this->ILikeCountCount )
    {
        // check if a $has_on realtion exist
        if ( !$this->ILikeCountID )
        {
            // create new DataObject + relation
            $ILikeCount = ILikeCount::create();
            $ILikeCount->Count = $this->ILikeCountCount;
            $ILikeCount->write();

            $this->ILikeCountID = $ILikeCount->ID;
        }
        else{
            // update existing relation
            $ILikeCount = $this->ILikeCount();
            $ILikeCount->Count = $this->ILikeCountCount;
            $ILikeCount->write();
        }  

        $this->ILikeCountCount = false; // clear to avoid duplicate writes
    }
    parent::onBeforeWrite();
}
```

Comment: hey! thats a cool idea! the only problem is to access the textfield and it´s value. $this->ILikeCountCount does for some reason not exist. i also tried to store the textfield in a private variable... i can echo it´s value in the getCMSFields function, but in the onBeforeWrite Function the textfield seems to be not accessible anymore.

Comment: that's weird, I've used this quite a few times and didn't have issue. Do you mind posting a link to your `getCMSFields()`?

Comment: the main issue I found is that in your code I could not see where you were creating the $has_one relation. So I've updated the code to create the `ILikeCount` object if it doesn't exist. This works fine on my setup.

Comment: cool I just pasted your code. that works perfectly. the only weird thing is: without the if statement `if( $this->ILikeCountCount )` it does not work. i think that was the problem before. thx